# Does Craft support gated content and form fills?

Tags: form

I'm a content marketer looking to get contact information for customers visiting my site. Does Craft support workflows with form fills?

For example:

1. User sees an ad for an ebook, white paper, or other marketing content. Goes to landing page > form fill with contact information > thank you page with content
2. User sees an ad for a webinar or other event. User goest to event page > form fill > thank you page with confirmation time.

Wondering if Craft supports this type of multi-step content workflow.

Answer (score 2):

Craft is definitely a good fit to manage content around these workflows, but the workflows themselves will require a bit of planning as to how they get implemented.

While there are several potential solutions, I'll share one workflow that can be used for this type of content using the [Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms) plugin (which my team is behind).

- Create a Landing Pages or Events Channel in Craft. Add whatever fields you want to customize your Landing Page or Events however you need to. These fields can be related to the content, layout, design; event information; or promotional content like the items you mentioned (ebook, white paper, etc)
- Create a Form in Sprout Forms for each type of lead capture form you want. You could have one that just requests an email; another that requests name, email, and a few other details; and another that let's a user select which event Date/Time they want to participate in.
- On the Landing Page Channel add the Forms Relations field. This will allow you to build flexible Landing pages with variations on your layout and design, as well as relate the form that you want to the Landing Pages or Event pages you are going to be sharing with your users.

After a user submits a form they will be redirected to a thank you page that you can set in the form settings. Depending on how you'd like to protect any content there are several different ways you could grant access to the page, but you have complete flexibility (some of these methods may require more setup than others):

- Just redirect and share the confirmation info or marketing content
- Redirect with a token that enables the content on the thank you page to only be seen by someone submitting the form
- Trigger an email to the user who submits the form with a unique link to the content you want them to have access to

Comment: Hey Ben - dragging this up from the past, I wonder if you could share more about what you meant by "redirect with a token"? What's a token and how do you include one on the redirect?

Comment: Not sure exactly what I meant. =). I could have meant query parameter or something more elaborate where you try to dynamically add a token to the redirect request. In reading this now, the easiest approach may just be to use the lastEntry tag in a conditional to just display something the request after the form is submitted: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/entries.html#lastentry